# Catch unexpected options with getopt

Tags: php, getopt

I am writing a PHP script and have to get some options (h, n and v). For me, the best way to get it is to use `getopt` function. Also, if an unexpected option is passed, I would like to display help message. However, `getopt` function only returns expteced options.

Here is my script:

```
$options = getopt('hnv');

if (!empty($options)) {
    foreach (array_keys($options) as $option) {
        switch ($option) {
            // Run script.
            case 'n':
            case 'v':
                break;
            case 'h':
                // Display help with OK exit code.
                self_usage();
                exit(0);
            default:
                // Display help with ERR exit code.
                self_usage('Too many params');
                exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

But, if I launch my script with an unexpected option like `-p`, it runs, because the options array is empty.

```
php myscript.php -p
```

If I pass an unexpected option with an expected one, it runs too.

```
php myscript.php -pn
php myscript.php -p -n
```

I've tried to check the passed args count, but this works only if I pass arguments one by one (`-n -p`) and not all in one (`-np`).

```
if ((count($argv) - 1) > count($options)) {
    self_usage();
}
```

Is there a good way to check for unexcepted options in all of this case?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
// remove script called
unset($argv[0]);
$valid_opts = getopt('hnv');
array_walk($argv, function(&$value, $key) {
    // get rid of not opts
    if(preg_match('/^-.*/', $value)) {
        $value = str_replace('-', '', $value);    
    } else {
        $value = '';
    }

});
$argv = array_filter($argv);
print_r($argv);
print_r($valid_opts);

print_r(array_diff($argv, array_keys($valid_opts)));
```

`array_diff`will give you the opts that are in the array that are not valid.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, if I launch my script using `php myscript.php -nh`, `nh` is considered as unexpected while it is. I edited your code to make it deal with this. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Way to find unexpected short options relying on getopt parsing method:

```
$all = getopt(implode('', array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'), range('0', '9'))));
$options = getopt('hnv');
$wrongOptions = array_diff(array_keys($all), array_keys($options));
if (!empty($wrongOptions)) {
    echo("Wrong options: " . implode(', ', $wrongOptions));
    exit(1);
}
```

You can also look at the tools like [zend.console.getopt](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.console.getopt.rules.html) especially if you want to verify long options as well.